# Как задать размер виджета в ячейке QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Помогите решить проблему.

В создаваемой таблице `QTableWidget` вставляю в ячейку кнопку. Кодом, которым она описывается, ниже. Все работает, но!

Форма с данной таблицей создается в конструкторе другой (главной) формы и, как я подозреваю, берет от туда некорректные размеры потому что кнопка в ячейке располагается по центру но не занимает весь размер ячейки, а приблизительно половину.

Никак не получается заставить ее растягиваться на всю ячейку.
Заранее спасибо!

```
QWidget *QOperatorList::createButtonWidget(QString s) const
{
    QWidget* wgt = new QWidget;
    QHBoxLayout* l = new QHBoxLayout;
    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton( s );
    connect( btn, SIGNAL( clicked( bool ) ), SLOT( onBtnClicked() ) );
    l->setMargin( 1 );
    l->setSpacing(1);
    l->addWidget( btn );
    l->setAlignment(btn, Qt::AlignCenter);
//    l->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
//    l->addStretch();
    wgt->setLayout( l );
    return wgt;
}
```

и, собственно вставка самой кнопки:

```
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(i, 3, createButtonWidget("O"));
```

Comment: setCellWidget(row, column, new QPushButton("O"));

Comment: Спасибо, но как слот добавить?

Comment: обратиться через cellWidget() ?

Comment: Действительно/, если вставлять кнопку без виджета, то она занимает всю ячейку. Connect прикрутить можно, но выглядит не очень. Нов любом случае работает. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо указать принцип заполнения родительского пространства:

```
//...
QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton();
btn->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
//...
```

И для wgt (QWidget*) сделать тоже самое

```
wgt->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую.

Comment: Принцип не работает.

Comment: @ВячеславЧерных Надо еще и для `wgt` этот метод вызвать

Comment: пробовал. Что в лоб, что по-лбу.